# Status code 500 when I click on my product

Tags: python, reactjs, django

This is my first time using redux and django. I click the link to one of my products that takes me to the products page, but I get a 500 error instead. My django server is running in the back and I know it's working because I get an error response in my terminal. I suspect my issue might be my views.py but I'm not sure since I'm not very familiar with django yet.

ProductPage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import ErrorMessage from "../components/Error";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProductsDetails } from "../actions/productActions";

function ProductPage() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProductsDetails(id));
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light my-3">
                Go Back
            </Link>
            {loading ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : error ? (
                <ErrorMessage variant="danger">{error}</ErrorMessage>
            ) : (
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                        <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={3}>
                        <ListGroup variant="flush">
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Rating
                                    value={product.rating}
                                    text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                                />
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <h3>Price: ${product.price}</h3>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                Description: {product.description}
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Col>

                    <Col md={3}>
                        <Card>
                            <ListGroup variant="flush">
                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Price:</Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Status:</Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Button
                                        className="btn-block"
                                        type="button"
                                        disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                                    >
                                        Add to Cart
                                    </Button>
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

productActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });

        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/");

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload:
                error.response && error.response.data.message
                    ? error.response.data.message
                    : error.message,
        });
    }
};

export const listProductsDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload:
                error.response && error.response.data.message
                    ? error.response.data.message
                    : error.message,
        });
    }
};
```

productReducers.js

```
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const productListReducers = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: [] };

        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                products: action.payload,
            };

        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const productDetailsReducers = (
    state = { product: { reviews: [] } },
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, ...state };

        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return { loading: false, product: action.payload };

        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .products import products
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        '/api/products/',
        '/api/products/create/',

        '/api/products/upload/',

        '/api/products/<id>/reviews/',

        '/api/products/top/',
        '/api/products/<id>',

        '/api/products/delete/<id>/',
        '/api/products/<update>/<id>/'
    ]
    return Response(routes)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()

    # uses serializer to convert our model in products into JSON format so it can be used in react
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You're going to want to check the logs on the server that's running Django. How are you running Django?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean? I just go into my backend folder and do python manage.py runserver. I don't know if that's what you mean

Comment: Django has built-in logging that you should configure to write logs to a logfile so you can see what's going on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/logging/ If possible, I would also recommend using PyCharm Professional, which has great Django support that lets you run your development server (runserver starts a *development only* server) with stdout being printed to a console viewer directly in the IDE, including clickable traceback on errors. You won't get far unless you know what the Django server is telling you went wrong. 500 is a generic server error.

Comment: are you sure you defined your Product primary key as `_id`? Typically Django would use `product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)` not `product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)`

Comment: @JimmyPells I definitely have product ids as _id in my products.js

Comment: @Audiopolis It seems like a nice option, but I can't really afford to pay for that service at the moment

Comment: I figured it out. On my ProductPage.js I had "id" in my useEffect hook instead of "_id".